# sonarQube execution failed with "Error during SonarQube Scanner execution"

Tags: java, tfs

I have sonar integrated with TFS. Was running fine since a long time. started failing with error regarding sonar scanner and java. I haven't upgraded anything or not changed anything. 
Error i am getting during TFS build,

**ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully**

can someone please advice?

Comment: Which kind of TFS build are you using? vNext or Msbuild

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - vNext build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by upgrading all plugins installed in SonarQube. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable more verbose logging to try to understand what exactly is failing. Follow below steps.

- Enable TFS Build debug logging by adding a variable named
  `system.debug` and setting its value to 'true'
- Enable the SonarQube components verbose logging - In your SonarQube
  Begin task, under Advanced > Additional Settings, please add:
  `/d:sonar.verbose=true`

And just follow the suggestion in error message.  `Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.` You could also have a look in the sonar.log of your SonarQube instance. May get more details of the error there.